# How do I zoom out on this screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried all ways to solve this problem:

- checking a blur bar(it was hidden)
- seeing the setting screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + wheeling down
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

but it doesn't work so far. It looks like this.

[image]

Comment: You can adjust the Zoom level in VS Code with the View > Appearance > Zoom commands. The zoom level increases or decreases by 20% each time a Zoom command is executed. View > Appearance > Zoom In ( Ctrl+=) - increase the Zoom level. View > Appearance > Zoom Out ( Ctrl+-) - decrease the Zoom level.

I got this from VSCODE official website

Comment: I can't really tell if you're asking something about programming, or if you are asking about computer software, which can be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Please consider checking/accepting the answer that worked for you. Read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) page.

Answer (score 0):

Accourding to the [Visual Studio Site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility), you can do this.

- View > Appearance > Zoom In (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>) - increase the Zoom level.
- View > Appearance > Zoom Out (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) - decrease the Zoom level.
- View > Appearance > Reset Zoom (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num0</kbd>) - reset the Zoom level
  to 0.

If its not working, check your extensions or try to reinstall VSC.

Comment: God..! it works. View > Appearance > reset zoom. i appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that